# Topologically unibranch in Mumfords book Complex Projective Varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-varieties

David Mumford gives in his book Algebraic Geometry I,
Complex Projective Varieties on page 43 the definition of
topologically unibranch points of affine variety and I have
a lot of problems to extract from this a way how to think about
unibranch points intuitively:

(3.9) Definition. Let $X$ be an affine variety (in this book always over $\mathbb{C}$)
and $x\in X$. Then $X$ is
topologically unibranch at $x$ if for all closed algebraic subsets $Y  \subsetneqq
X$, $x$ has fundamental system neighborhoods $U_n$ in
classical topology of $X$ s.t. $U_n-(U_n\cap Y)$ is connected.

Then Mumford continues:

Note that smooth points are topologically unibranch: in fact if $x$ is smooth on $X$,
$x$ has analytic coordinates in a neighborhood $U$ (according to Corollary 1.26):

$$\alpha:  \text{ polycylinder } V_{\epsilon} := \{z \in \mathbb{C}^r \vert \ 
\vert z_i \vert < \epsilon \} \xrightarrow[\cong]{\alpha} U \subset X$$

$$ \text{ with  } \ \ \ \ \ 0 \mapsto x$$

Essentially, $U$ becomes affine space.
Every (alg closed subset) $Y \subsetneqq X$ is contaned in the set of zeroes of
some polynomial $p$ which not vanish on $X$. Hence $\alpha^{-1}(Y)$ is contaned
in the set of zeroes of some convergent power series $q(z_1,...,z_n)$
which doesn't vanish identically.

And then Mumford clamed that the set
$V_{\epsilon} - (\text{ zeroes of } q)$ is connected. His "argument":
If $x,y \in V_{\epsilon} - (\text{ zeroes of } q)$, look at line
$tx+(1-t)y$ joining them (vector notation). Then
$tx+(1-t)y \in V_{\epsilon} - (\text{ zeroes of } q)$ if
$\vert t-\frac{1}{2} \vert \le \frac{1}{2}$ and $q(tx+(1-t)y)$ has only a finite
set of zeroes on the
disc $\vert t-\frac{1}{2} \vert < \frac{1}{2}$. Thus $x$ and $y$ can be joint by a path avoiding
zeroes of $q$]. But what if $X$ is $2$-dimensional and $Y$ one-dimensional and contains $x$,
for example if $Y$ is an affine line, see my conterexmple below in P1?

problems:

**P1**: where lives the parameter $t$ of the line $tx+(1-t)y$ introduced in
the proof? Mumford called the definition domain of $t$ the
disc $\vert t-\frac{1}{2} \vert < \frac{1}{2}$. Is it the *complex* ! disc
$B_{\frac{1}{2}}(\frac{1}{2})= \{z \in \Bbb C \ \vert \ 
\vert z-\frac{1}{2} \vert < \frac{1}{2} \}$ or the "real" disc around $\frac{1}{2}$ which is in our case $[0,1]$? My guess is $B_{\frac{1}{2}}(\frac{1}{2})$ because for $t \in [0,1]$ the proof looks wrong.
The zeroes of $q(tx+(1-t)y)$ cannot be avoided running $t$ in $[0,1]$.

as KReiser noticed in his comment my "conterexample" is wrong
since X−Y={(x,y)|x≠0} is connected in C2 but not R2 and the later
was the picture in had previously in mind. That is the next question P2 can be
ignored:

<s>**P2**: I think the proof is wrong. Take for example the affine plane $X= U = \mathbb{C}^2$ and $x=(0,0)$. Clearly $x$ is smooth in $X$. Take as $Y$ the vanishing set
of monomial $z_1 \in \mathbb{C}[z_1,z_2]$. Then $x \in Y$ and $Y$ "slices" $X$
in two parts along $y$-axis: $X-Y= \{(x,y) \vert x \neq 0 \}$</s>

Then every open neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ in
is divided by $Y$ in two parts as well and so $U - U \cap Y$ can never be connected.
So according to this definition of topologically unibranchness even affine plane isn't unibranch, yeah? Therefore I want to clarify if the book's definition of topologically unibranch is indeed wrong or did I miss something.

**P3**: And moreover I would like to know how to think about topologically unibranchness
intuitively. Is there any way to visualize geometrically what is going on there?

Comment: it would be nice if in future the downvoter could at least take a few minutes to leave a short comment 
on the reason for downvoting. Certainly my questions have room 
for improvement but without feedback it is difficult to progress.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but surely you're not claiming that $\Bbb C \setminus 0$ is disconnected in P1, right?

Comment: yes my "conterexample" isn't a conterexample, I see. In complex case the subset 
$\{(x,y) \vert x \neq 0 \} \subsetneqq \mathbb{C}^2$ is connected. 
This is what you wanted to get at with the obvious connetedness of 
$\Bbb C \setminus 0$? The error of mine seems to be that I was thinking
too real since the same set is certainly not connected in $\mathbb{R}^2$:)

Comment: probably I found also the cause for my confusion with the line trick in the
proof. When Mumford considers the line $tx+(1-t)y$ the parameter $t$ 
is assumed to be complex with $t \in B_{\frac{1}{2}}(\frac{1}{2})$ and not
real with $t \in [0,1]$ as usually used in topology, right? the proof only 
seems only to work if we consider $t$ as an element in the complex domain.